# .Renviron getting overwritten by globalVariables

Tags: r, data.table, lintr

Let's say I have a function in my package

```r
my_fn <- function() {
  mtcars_dt <- data.table::data.table(mtcars)
  mtcars_dt[, mpg_div_hp := mpg / hp]
  mtcars_dt
}
```

In my `.Renviron` I have the setting `_R_CHECK_CODETOOLS_PROFILE_="suppressUndefined=TRUE"`. This will ensure that when the `codetools` package is ran during the `R CMD check`, it will not return any warnings such as

```
my_fn: no visible binding for global variable 'mpg_div_hp'
```

However, if I have defined some global variables, such as

```
utils::globalVariables(c("mpg", "hp"))
```

within my package documentation, the `R CMD check` will identify *all* variables as unbound. It is almost as if the `globalVariables()` function is overwriting the `"suppressUndefined=TRUE"` option within my `.Renviron` file.

My question is why is this happening? For more context, please read on.

There are seemingly two "simple" soluitons:

1. Do not define any variables within my `package.R` file and allow the `codetools` option to handle them all.
2. Define all global variables within the `globalVariables()` function and don't use the `codetools` option.

Unfortunately the first option isn't great if you want to use the `lintr` package as `lintr` only checks the RHS of the `mpg_div_hp := mpg / hp` part of the function. So including the variables `"mpg"` and `"hp"` in the `globalVariables` function is why I have come across this issue. Of course I can use the `object_usage_linter=NULL` option for `lintr`, but this feels unsatisfactory. The second option would require a vector of >1000 variables which does not feel like a nice solution.

Comment: Known scoping issue with R that arises from `data.table` use, and the recommendation has always been to "silence" it by listing all affected variables.  So to me that suggests it is partially self-inflicted (you skipped `mpg_div_hp`), and partially the fault of `lintr`.